# Compare part of Combobox1.value with combobox2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have created a userform with comboboxes, I would like to compare the a part of combobox 2 with the value of combobox 1. if they do not match there should be an error given (as in my code, see below), the code that I made is not working, but I do not know what is wrong.

the error that is showing is:

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined @Find

```
If Left(Me.ComboBox2.Value(Find(" -", Me.ComboBox2.Value, 1) - 1)) <> Me.ComboBox1 Then
  MsgBox "The tag of " & m2.ComboBox2.Tag & "does not match with selected BIN"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Please, try `If Instr(Me.ComboBox2.value, me.ComboBox1.value) >0 then`. This is `True` if part of `me.ComboBox1.value` is found in `me.ComboBox2.value`...

Comment: @FaneDuru, thnx for your assistance, but it seems that this is not working.

Comment: This is certainly working if what you wrote in the question is correct... And it depends on what do you expect from the code line I posted, too.

Comment: I like your approach to compare the content of Combobox2 with combobox1. but it lets assume in combobox1 i put "BIN 4", and in Combobox2 "BIN 2 - A - B - C". it should give the error `MsgBox "The tag of " & me.ComboBox2.Tag & "does not match with selected BIN"` but it does not also it should exit the sub but it does not exit the sub and just continues executing the other parts of my code.

Comment: How can we know anything about your these **other parts**, if you did not show them? How could I know what you try doing, if you do not explain this aspect? **In words**, if in code is difficult... You din not mentioned, at least, that you use it in a loop. If, for instance, you need exiting the loop after the message, you should place `:Exit For` after it. If you are talking about a loop `For i = ... Next i`, or `:Exit Do` for a lop `Do ... Loop`... You can even exit the whole sub placing `Exit Sub`. But it is impossible to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: thnx again, in my point of view there is no need for a loop. it just needs to compare the left part untill " -" of combobox2 with the value in combobox1, if this is not identical, it should give an error and exit the sub. Or like your approach, if value in combobox1 is not part of combobox2 then give the error.

Comment: I am afraid your "point of view" is imitated, no offence... You did not explain what you try doing and talking about "it does not exit the sub and just continues executing the other parts of my code", **without seeing the code** I made some assumptions. I also do not understand what "it should give an error" should mean. If a message, you should place `Exit Sub` after the message in discussion...

Comment: what i mean with the error is actually the MsgBox.

Comment: Then, adding `Exit Sub` should stop the code there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working already with the following code, thanks anyway for the help.

`If Left(Me.ComboBox2.Value, InStr(Me.ComboBox2.Value, " -") - 1) <> Me.ComboBox1 Then`

`MsgBox "The tag of " & me.ComboBox2.Tag & "does not match with selected BIN"`

`Exit Sub`

`End If`